# How to write main flask initialize file for an MVC app

Tags: python, api, rest, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use MVC architecture pattern with flask application but I'm getting circular import error when using routing before initializing SQLAlchemy. I am not able to understand the flow of where should I initialize SQLAlchemy since it is required by both model and controller and if initialized in app file then I am getting different error. I'm terrible in explaining my problem but I'm sharing github link to go through whole source code for better understanding.

Please explain the problem with this architecture as to how I can improvise and make it more scabable.
[Source Code](https://github.com/centtex/mvcApi)

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This link takes me to `page not found` web page

Comment: Kindly update this source code link

Comment: @SamVarghese the link is working now. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: I don't know how to address a solution to your problem, but I strongly recommend [reading this Flask tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-a-better-application-structure), I'm sure many parts of it will help you if you read them thoroughly.

Comment: @EduardoFreireMangabeira i followed this tutorial and came up with my own design pattern which i am trying to implement but i am just missing the basic referencing part

Comment: @phd can you please solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a `.flaskenv` file that reads

```
FLASK_APP=app.py
FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

But the file that starts your application up (entrypoint) is called `centuryApi.py`

so change `.flaskenv` to this

```
FLASK_APP=centuryApi.py
FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

Comment: Yeah it was a mistake please ignore this. Can you explain me the real issue I really need this app working

Comment: Apart from what’s mentioned in this answer I can’t reproduce your problem. Update the question and repo so the problem is reproducible for others.

Comment: cannot import name 'db' from partially initialized module 'centuryApi' i am getting this error when running flask app

Comment: can you explain where should I import modules for migration and routes to register blueprint in centuryapi file bcz both the module require db object and I am facing the issue in sequence as to where should i initialize db for models and for controllers